# Database schema for user reviews

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am working on user reviews with this columns:

- product_id
- communication
- cleanliness
- location
- value

Each column can be number from 1-5. My question is how to calculate average grade for each column with out calling all reviews from database and calculating it every time.

So I was thinking to put in product table:

- communication_sum_of_grades
- communication_number_of_reviews
- ... etc

and than do: 
average= communication_sum_of_grades / communication_number_of_reviews

My question is if this is right approach?

Comment: Wouldn't using the SQL engine's `COUNT` and `AVG` functions be way more efficient?

Comment: Well I am not sure maybe is faster to just increment communication_sum_of_grades and communication_number_of_reviews when user submit review then make sql query every time someone open product...

Comment: Calculating average in this fashion might be faster, but will not be much much faster. Real question is if you really need this slight increase in performance and are you aware that you are introducing a potential point of failure by inserting new columns to your db and putting logic to modify them in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are `large number of records` and query for average reviews are `very frequent` then your method will be `efficient` because in this case writing will be a `touch heavy` `but reading will be very fast`. But in case the query for average reviews is not that frequent then you may go for the triditional method of fetching all rows and finding avarage.

hope it helps :)